# Keycloak export realm settings

Tags: docker, docker-compose, export, keycloak

I have `Keycloak` v21.1.1 running on `Docker` with `docker compose` and this is part of the `yaml`-file:

```
services:
  keycloak:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:latest
    container_name: keycloak-auth
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "8787:8787"
    networks:
      - keycloaknet
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: ${KEYCLOAK_ADMIN} 
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: ${KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD}
      DEBUG: true
      DEBUG_PORT: "*:8787"
      DB_VENDOR: POSTGRES
      DB_ADDR: postgres
      DB_PORT: 5432
      DB_DATABASE: ${POSTGRES_DB}
      DB_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER}
      DB_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      TZ: Europe/Paris
    env_file:
      - development.env
    volumes:
      - //d/Backup/Keycloak:/tmp/export
    command:
      [
        'start-dev'
      ]
```

Now I want to export realm settings like described [here](https://www.keycloak.org/server/importExport). However, when I execute

```
docker exec $containerId /opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh export --dir /tmp/export --users different_files
```

I get the following error messages

```
ERROR: transport error 202: bind failed: Address already in use
ERROR: JDWP Transport dt_socket failed to initialize, TRANSPORT_INIT(510)
JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197): No transports initialized [src/jdk.jdwp.agent/share/native/libjdwp/debugInit.c:734]
```

I am a bit lost here and also tried to modify the `yaml` file to export realm settings at each startup in the `command` section by replacing `start-dev` with `export --dir /tmp/export --users different_files`, which does export the settings, but immediately shuts down afterwards.

How can I fix this?